# Using Field Value in setEnpoint() URL

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, geolocation

I am trying to send a request to a google api and I am using the following setEndpoint():

```
request.setEndpoint('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyAOTbFK4154NH6AfFra1Sol4Ok-zpqAgvE');
```

I would like this to use a custom field on the Account called `Billing_Address_Text__c` but when I plug that in like below

```
request.setEndpoint('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={!Account.Billing_Address_Text__c}&key=AIzaSyAOTbFK4154NH6AfFra1Sol4Ok-zpqAgvE');
```

I get the following error:

```
expecting a right parentheses, found 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={!Account.Billing_Address_Text__c}&key=AIzaSyAOTbFK4154NH6AfFra1Sol4Ok-zpqAgvE'
```

*Edit*

Here is my entire Apex Class

```
public class CallGoogleGeocodeAPI {
@future(callout=true)
public static void parseJSONResponse() {
    Http http = new Http();
    //Create HTTP request to send.
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    //Set the endpoint URL.
    PageReference endPoint = new PageReference('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json');
    endPoint.getParameters().put('address', accountRecord.Billing_Address_Text__c);
    endPoint.getParameters().put('key','AIzaSyAOTbFK4154NH6AfFra1Sol4Ok-zpqAgvE');
    request.setEndpoint(endPoint.getUrl());
    //Set the HTTP verb to GET.
    request.setMethod('GET');
    //Send the HTTP Request and get the response.
    //The response is in JSON format.
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    System.debug(response.getBody());
    //Parse the JSON response to get the latitude and longitude.
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());
    String location;
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'location')) {
            //Get the value.
            parser.nextToken();
            location += parser.getText();
        }
    }
    System.debug('The location is ' + location);
}
}
```

I am currently receiving an error: `Variable does not exist: accountRecord.Billing_Address_Text__c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't generally use merge fields in Apex (except for Dynamic Visualforce components). Instead, you'd use normal string concatenation, or my personal preference, a PageReference:

```
PageReference endPoint = new PageReference('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json');
endPoint.getParameters().put('address', accountRecord.Billing_Address_Text__c);
endPoint.getParameters().put('key','your-google-api-key-here');
request.setEndpoint(endPoint.getUrl());
```

This method automatically takes care of all of the pesky details with concatenation, URL-encoding, and so on.

Comment: How would I modify this for a custom object `Branch__c'?

Comment: I am going to add the full code to this question and also the error I am getting now.

Comment: @cmmoutes13 you need to query a record from the database. This means you will probably need to pass an ID parameter to your function.

Comment: What if I wanted to have an Apex Trigger call this apex class?

Comment: Actually, scratch that last comment. Okay, so lets say that I wanted to have this class run for every Account in the instance where that Billing_Address_Text__c field was != null. Could I do that? Instead of having a trigger to run this class?

Comment: @cmmoutes13 you can write a batch class to process as many records as you would like. You can do a search for batch Apex call out here on SF SE.

Comment: Okay thanks fox. Ill check it out. Also congrats on 100K